# How to add custom marker in google map in android

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I'm using google map and  I want to add a custom marker to my app, the image which I want to add is in drawable and its name is "fedfefe" but my app is crashing, if use default marker then it's working fine

**Below is my code:**

```
package com.example.mapdemo;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 

 OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng pune= new LatLng(18.522866, 73.856057);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pune).title("pune").snippet( "hello world").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.fedfefe)));

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pune, 1 ));
     }
   }
```

Comment: It can help if you add your error logs

Comment: maybe trouble with you drawable, please show your path to the file "R.drawable.fedfefe"